# IOTA "C" version (CClient) and feasibility of signing transactions on ESP32?

Tags: legacy-protocol, internet-of-things, signing, proof-of-work, energy-consumption

An article recently has been published entitled **"Running the IOTA "CClient" library on ESP32"** ([>>>Link to Article<<<](https://blog.iota.org/running-the-iota-cclient-library-on-esp32-4a1a5191afad)).

It is not clear to me if by using this C version of IOTA is practicable to **run PoW** or **signing transactions** on ESP32 device?

Since in this answer ([>>>Link to Answer<<<](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/2140/1928)) is mentioned that:

> "It is **not** feasible to **compute the Proof-of-Work on microcontrollers** due to **their limited computational speed**. Furthermore, the official CCurl implementation (Proof-of-Work computation in C) uses the `pthreads` library and other functionality which are **not** typically **available on microcontrollers**.
>   It is, in my opinion, not feasible to run IOTA in battery powered
>   embedded devices due to the large amount of energy it takes to sign
>   transactions, **even if the Proof-of-Work is done elsewhere**."

The question is that:

- Can this C version of IOTA make it **feasible** to **run PoW** or to **sign transactions** on micro-controllers?
- **in general**, how can this C version improve running IOTA on micro-controllers? And **what new opportunities does C version bring us?**

Answer (score 0):

> - Can this C version of IOTA make it feasible to run PoW or to sign transactions on micro-controllers?

Not exactly, the application runs on FreeRTOS and pthread is supported on ESP32, but it's not recommended to run PoW on ESP32, you won't be satisfied with the time-spending and system resources. 
In my opinion, ESP32 is not a legacy microcontroller, it's system on chip(SoC) and easy to do PoC for the IoT product.

> - in general, how can this C version improve running IOTA on micro-controllers? And what new opportunities does C version bring us?

A microcontroller might be 8-bit/16-bit and only has 256KB SRAM/Flash or less, what are the reasons for running IOTA on it which without network stack and limited RAM/Flash?

Considering an IoT system, many devices run on embedded systems with limited resources and usually use C/C++ for its application. [Entangled](https://github.com/iotaledger/entangled) is a set of libraries can provide the Tangle protocol in C/C++ besides, calling C from other programming language is not a problem.