# How many type of Proof-of-Work is used in IOTA?

Tags: pow, proof-of-work, energy-consumption, iot

In the following article about "IOTA CryptoCore", it is written:

> "IOTA core functions like address generation, signing, “**Mini-Pow**” and
>   **Proof of Work (PoW)** need much computational power which makes it
>   almost impossible (in a practical sense) to be done by small embedded
>   systems."

1. What is the difference of **Mini-Pow** with **Proof of Work (PoW)** ?
2. And when they say:

> "The PoW-core was later integrated into the IOTA Crypto Core."

Which PoW do they mean? **Mini-Pow** or **Proof of Work (PoW)** ? (Regarding to the fact that they say also:

> "signing and PoW **need much computational power** which makes it almost
>   **impossible** (in a practical sense) to be done by **small embedded
>   systems**."

Comment: what is pow position in iota and its use?

Answer (score 2):

1) In mid 2017 the M-Bug was found and the work-around for it is (inoficially) called "Mini-PoW". It could happen that a Bundle-Hash contained "M" which exposed a private key (and all following keys) directly and weakened signatures significantly. The Workaround simply recreates bundle-hashs until no "M" is contained within the hash. This is a brute-force work-around for which reason it was also called "Mini-PoW". Actually it's not PoW at all, but it should* be done for signatures. The computational work of Mini-Pow vs PoW is about 1:200, so it's more an inconvenience than a real PoW. If in IOTA context is written about PoW, always the real PoW is meant.

2) The real PoW-core was integrated in the IOTA Crypto Core. "Mini-PoW" is more a software-thing which uses hardware-acceleration for keccak384 hashing but it really is more software whereas PoW is done completly on the FPGA.

*should means: it's done in every IOTA library but nodes would accept Bundle-Hashes with 'M's. In contrary transactions containing a wrong PoW-nonce would be rejected. But it's in everyone's interest to do the "Mini-PoW" for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only two points remains yet unclear to me: (1) What do you mean by **'M'** ? And (2) Is **"CryptoCore"** a micro-controller (or FPGA) which is able to do PoW completely ? (Because I heard that micro-controllers are not able to perform PoW.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer.

1) The "M-bug" is effectively the normalized bundle-hash containing the character M.
More information about it here:
[Why is the normalized hash considered insecure when containing the char 'M'](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/why-is-the-normalized-hash-considered-insecure-when-containing-the-char-m)

2) Proof-of-Work was implemented in VHDL between 26th April '18 and 26th Aug '18 and became the PiDiver: https://github.com/shufps/iota_vhdl_pow (Source: https://gitlab.com/iccfpga/iccfpga-core/wikis/home)

Where did you hear that micro-controllers are not able to perform PoW?

edit:
Micro-controllers and PoW are not the best combination, one solution to it is [Azimuth](https://blog.iota.org/eli9-azimuth-previously-known-as-nb-pow-f36156d378e4)

Comment: **Here:** https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/2140/1928 , ( "_... It is not feasible to compute the Proof-of-Work on microcontrollers due to their limited computational speed. Furthermore, the official CCurl implementation (Proof-of-Work computation in C) uses the pthreads library and other functionality which are not typically available on microcontrollers._") And **Here:** https://ecosystem.iota.org/projects/iota-pearl-diver-pow-fpga-raspberry-pi , "_... PoW need much computational power which makes it almost impossible to be done by small embedded systems._"

Comment: Thanks for your links. As you can see, there are different approaches to solve the PoW issue for IoT.

Comment: Yes, for example, one of the approaches is **outsourced PoW server**; however, in that case, PoW is **not** done on the micro-controller, but on an external trusted server. But I mean performing PoW locally and directly on the micro-controller.